# Difference between periodic oscillation and periodic movement

Tags: homework-and-exercises

I'm dealing with a problem here.
I'm not sure about the answer of this question: "What is the difference between periodic oscillation and periodic movement?".
-For my opinion the difference is that the periodic oscillation changes the side but the periodic movement doesn't(if it changes the side than it is an oscillation) and I also  think that the periodic oscillation is a movement back and forth at a regular speed instead of periodic movement which is a motion that recurs over and over and the period of time required for each recurrence remains the same(which means that it isn't a movement back and forth).

Can anybody help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that "periodic movement" need not be oscillatory.  For example, consider an object that moves right for one minute, stops for one minute and repeats.  This would be periodic movement in the sense of [occuring at regular intervals](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/periodic).

And, while oscillation implies back and forth movement (if we're still talking about movement), it need not be periodic.